# How to execute sql server query from another machine using bat file?

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, batch-file

I've 2 servers.

Server1 contains SQL server database installed. 
Server2 is normal windows server without SQL database.

I want to write a bat file on Server1. It has to connect to Server1 (by passing connection string etc.), execute a query and return the output to Server1. Can anyone help??

Using readymade tools/exe such as PsExec is not allowed on servers.

Using VB/C# script can be another way but then I've make Executable of it and place on application server. It may also be denied by IT-admin.

I'm looking for set of dos commands which can be placed in bat file and I will put it in application server.

### Please suggest/explain any other method, like placing bat file on database server and calling it from application server.

Hi guys,

Thanks for your help.
I'm able to connect to execute a sql query on database server by using a bat running on app server.
Used "sqlcmd" for this.

But now the hurdle is that IT Admin is asking to use ODBC connection and not "sqlcmd".

Can you please guide me how to use ODBC connection in bat file and connect to remote database?

Comment: is sqlcmd utility allowed?

Comment: 3rd tect block is a little confusing, do you mean you want the bat file and output on Server 2?

Comment: I've now written a bat file on SQL server (server1) itself. It contains sqlcmd utility. It executes query and saves output in Server1 itself. Now my problem is to call this bat file from application server (server2). This server2 does not contain sqlcmd.

Comment: install sqlcmd from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36433

Comment: hi dean, thanks for suggestion. but IT-admin not allowing to install sqlcmd on application server(server2) because it is already available in database server(server1). I need to write a bat file (say connectbat.bat) on server1 which will connect to server2 (may be using hostname, userlogin and password) and call another bat file placed in server2 (in which I already written sqlcmd for query execution).

Comment: If this is a business need and you have to execute from another server you will have to get IT to allow it. Anything else e.g. telnet, task scheduler, psexec would just be working around their regulations

Comment: guys, I've revised the description in question. please help me out on making odbc connection in bat file for query execution.

Comment: Yes you can write a VBScript or powershell (or anything else) to do this. Sounds like your IT Admin is a bit power mad.

Comment: "execute a query and return the output to Server1" what do you mean? where does the output go - into a file?

Comment: and this... http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/e580a1e1-f116-4fc5-9344-bebf4489dc75/running-sql-query-with-powershell-on-remote-server?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: @ElectricLlama - thanks for suggestion. But I want to know how to create and use ODBC connection in batch file itself. VBScript or dotNet or Java will also require some components to install. Right?

Comment: And Yes, the output of sql query is captured in a file.

Comment: VBScript is packaged with Windows. As is the .NET Framework and PowerShell (PowerShell has been included by default since Server 2008R2/Win7, and is a standard Windows component offered through Microsoft Update). Your IT admin is, IMHO, being a bit unreasonable here.

Comment: You cannot use an ODBC connection directly in a batch file. You can call a powershell script or a VBScript with a batch file. You can call a third party EXE that uses ODBC, But you cannot use ODBC directly in a batch file. Why do you need to use it directly in a batch file?

Answer (score 0):

Start with this code to establish that you can connect. Paste it into a .txt file and rename to .vbs:

You need to create a DSN (data source name) in odbc admin (odbcad32.exe) called MyDSN that connects to your SQL Server. There is a way to do this without needing to create a DSN but I forget that right now.

```
Dim oCon

Call Main


Private Sub Main()

'----------------------------------------------------------------------
' Create ADO objects
Set oCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")


oCon.ConnectionString = "DSN=MyDSN;Uid=scratch;Pwd=;"
oCon.Open


If oCon.State <> 1 Then
Call MsgBox("Could not connect to the database")
Exit Sub
Else
Call MsgBox("Connected to the database")
End If  
'----------------------------------------------------------------------
End Sub
```

Once you have that working I can help further.